# Does using currying result in lower performance in F#?

Tags: f#, currying

When writing a function that can accept currying, you can write it as a single-argument function that returns a function.  For example,

```
let add x =
    let inner y = x + y
    inner
```

So you can either do:

```
add 3 4
```

or:

```
let add3 = add 3
add3 4
```

My question, is because you return a function, you are conceptually calling a function twice (the outer function and the inner function).  Is this slower than:

```
let add x y = x + y
```

or does the compiler optimise invocations of `add 3 4` in the curried definition?

Comment: Oops!  I was typing from memory.  I will edit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
let f x   = fun y -> x + y
let g x y = x + y
```

Looking at these function definitions in dnSpy for an optimized build reveals them to be:

```
public static int f(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}

public static int g(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

This is not that strange because `g` is actually a short-hand definition for `f` which is the general case. In F#-like languages function conceptually always take a single value returning a single value. Values might be functions. This is easier to see if one paranthese the function signature for `f` and `g`

```
val f: int -> int -> int
// Actually is
// val f: int -> (int -> int)
// ie f is a function that takes a single int and returns a function that takes a single int and returns an int.
```

In order to get F# to execute faster on .NET the physical representation of `f` in an assembly is:

```
public static int f(int x, int y)
```

While this is a more natural representation of the F# function.

```
public static Func<int, int> f(int x)
```

Would perform poorly though.

Usually F# is clever enough to avoid the overhead of the abstraction by optimization like above and on invocation. However, there are situations where F# can't optimize for you.

Imagine that you are implementing `fold`

```
let rec fold f s vs =
  match vs with
  | v::vs -> fold f (f s v) vs
  | []    -> s
```

Here F# can't fully optimize `f s v`. The reason is that `f` might have a more complex implementation than above that might return a different function depending on `s`.

If you look in `dnSpy` you note that F# are invoking function using `InvokeFast` but this does an internal test to see if it can be invoked fast. In fold we then do this test for each value even though this is the same function.

This is the reason one might sometimes see `fold` written like this:

```
let fold f s vs =
  let f = OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<_, _, _>.Adapt f
  let rec loop s vs =
    match vs with
    | v::vs -> loop (f.Invoke (s, v)) vs
    | []    -> s
  loop s vs
```

`Adapt` here tests before the loop if `f` can indeed be optimized and then returns an efficient adapter. In the general case it might still be a bit slower but then this is what the caller intended.

Note; this potential performance degradation doesn't happen for simple function values like `'T -> 'U`. This can always be invoked efficiently.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

I tested this in [LINQPad 5](https://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx).

When compiler optimizations are turned off, the F# compiler will produce different IL for each snippet. In other words, if there are any optimizations going on, it's left up to the JITter, and it may very well be slower to call the first form.

However, when compiler optimizations are turned on, both forms produce identical IL outputs in every scenario I could think of to test it. In fact, with both forms, calling:

```
add 3 4
```

yields the IL equivalent of a hard-coded `7`, with the entire function call optimized away:

```
ldc.i4.7
```

In other words, the F# compiler is pretty thorough when it comes to optimizing logically identical code blocks.

This is not an exhaustive answer, of course, and there could be some case where they are actually treated differently by the compiler.